# Degrees of freedom in a spinor in $d$ dimensions (following Polchinski & Lounesto)

Tags: spacetime, representation-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I am working through several texts on spinors and trying to deepen my understanding of this fascinating concept. In many ways I have found Polchinski's great Appendix B of String Theory, volume 2 to be the clearest, but struggle to reconcile it with the treatment by e.g. Lounesto (Clifford Algebras and Spinors), Jürgen Jost (Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis), and especially David Hestenes and other proponents of (real) Geometric algebra (GA) (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0403040v2).

The part that is causing me difficulty is the following. Polchinski starts by defining creation and annihilation operators in a Clifford algebra $Cl_{d-1, 1}(\mathbb{C})$ of $d = 2k + 2$ total dimensions as
$$ \begin{aligned} \Gamma^{0\pm} &= \tfrac 1 2 (\pm \Gamma^0 + \Gamma^1) \\
\Gamma^{a\pm} &= \tfrac 1 2 (\Gamma^{2a} \pm i\Gamma^{2a+1}),
 \end{aligned}$$
satifying $\{ \Gamma^{a\pm}, \Gamma^{b\pm}\} = 0$ and $\{ \Gamma^{a+}, \Gamma^{b-}\} = \delta^{ab}$ for all $a = 0, 1, \ldots, k$.

He then defines a spinor $\zeta$ which is annihilated by all $\Gamma^{a-}$:
$$ \Gamma^{a-} \zeta = 0. $$
From this lowest rung, we can define spinor representations $\zeta^{(\mathbf{s})}$ of dimension $2^{k+1}$,  given by

$$ \zeta^{(\mathbf{s})} = (\Gamma^{k+})^{s_k + 1/2} \cdots (\Gamma^{0+})^{s_0 + 1/2} \zeta = 0, $$

where $\mathbf{s} = (s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_k)$ labels the representations, with $s_a = \pm \tfrac 1 2$.

From the fact that $\zeta$ is annihilated by all annihilation operators, I would assume that $\zeta$ is of the form
$$ \zeta = (\prod_{a=0}^k \Gamma^{a-}) \eta.$$

My question is: what is the type and dimension of $\eta$? Since the Clifford algebra is of dimension $d = 2k + 2$, is has matrix representations of $2^{d/2} \times 2^{d/2} = 2^{k+1} \times 2^{k+1}$ as explained by Polchinski. Is it therefore correct to say that $\eta \in Cl_{d-1, 1}(\mathbb{C})$, and that it is projected down to a "column vector" of dimension $2^{k+1}$ by idempotents of the type $\Gamma^{a+}\Gamma^{a-}$?

If so, this would bridge my understanding between the various texts because Lounesto shows that $k+1$ such commuting idempotents of the type $\Gamma^{a+}\Gamma^{a-}$ do indeed form $k+1$ minimal left ideals when acting on the Clifford algebra $Cl_{d-1, 1}$, which would correspond to the representations of Polchinki with only one $s_a=1/2$ and all others $-1/2$. And it would explain why proponents of real GA are able to derive so many properties just with $\eta \in Cl_{d-1, 1}$, since GA removes the need for "column vectors" and instead treats both the transformations and the vector spaces on which they operates as elements of the same algebra.

If not, I'd love to hear where I'm wrong.